# R - How to rbind two lists while alternating their list elements

Tags: r

I'd like to know how to rbind two lists containing vectors into a data frame. e.g.

```
a<-list(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,4,5,6))
b<-list(c(3,4,5,6,7), c(4,5,6,7,8))
```

How to make a data frame from the two lists as the following:

```
1 2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 
4 5 6 7 8
```

So I need to take the first element of each list and then rbind them. Then take the second element of each list and then rbind to the previous data frame. I know I could use a for loop but is there a better and faster way to do this?

Comment: Please mark answers solved so that the community knows and people looking for the same answer in the future can more quickly find the answer. I think @thelatemail's answer is probably most flexible/efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variation on @DiscoSuperfly's answer that will work with objects of uneven length, like:

```
a <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,4,5,6), c(1,1,1,1,1))
b <- list(c(3,4,5,6,7), c(4,5,6,7,8))
```

An answer:

```
L <- list(a,b)
L <- lapply(L, `length<-`, max(lengths(L)))
do.call(rbind, do.call(Map, c(rbind, L)))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    3    4    5    6    7
#[3,]    2    3    4    5    6
#[4,]    4    5    6    7    8
#[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)
map2_dfr(a, b, ~data.frame(rbind(.x, .y)))

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5  6  7
3  2  3  4  5  6
4  4  5  6  7  8
```

Comment: Base R translation - `data.frame(do.call(rbind, Map(rbind, a, b)))`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for sharing the base R translation

Answer (score 2):

Of the answers given, this seems the fastest when using two lists, thanks in large part to @thelatemail's suggested edit (thanks!).

Try this:

```
rbab<-do.call(rbind,c(a,b)); rbind(rbab[c(TRUE,FALSE),],rbab[c(FALSE,TRUE),])
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7
[3,]    2    3    4    5    6
[4,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

Using c(TRUE,FALSE) above rbinds every other line a and b; then we flip that to c(FALSE,TRUE) to get the rest. Finally, we rbind it all together.

**EDIT: Speed Test**

Here's a larger scale speed test, for an objective comparison, which used two lists of 6000 elements each instead of the original a and b provided. A total of 100 iterations were used to estimate these statistics.

```
#Sample used:
a<-list(c(1,2,3,4,5),c(2,3,4,5,6))
b<-list(c(3,4,5,6,7),c(4,5,6,7,8))
a<-a[rep(1:2,3e3)]
b<-a[rep(1:2,3e3)]

#Here is the collaboration version (with @thelatemail): 
func1 <- function(){
  rbab<-do.call(rbind,c(a,b)); rbind(rbab[c(TRUE,FALSE),],rbab[c(FALSE,TRUE),])
}

#Here is my original version: 
func2 <- function(){
  rbind(do.call(rbind,c(a,b))[c(TRUE,FALSE),],do.call(rbind,c(a,b))[c(FALSE,TRUE),])
}

#Here's a base-R translation of @ycw's answer (*translated by thelatemail)
func3 <- function(){
  do.call(rbind, Map(rbind, a, b))
}

#Here is @Onyambu's answer (also a great answer for its brevity!): 
func4 <- function(){
  Reduce(rbind,Map(rbind,a,b))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  func1(),func2(),func3(),func4()
)

Unit: microseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 func1()      4.39      6.46     14.74     15.85     20.24     31.94   100   
 func2()   5789.26   6578.83   7114.21   7027.57   7531.52   9411.05   100   
 func3()  10279.50  10970.70  11611.90  11245.47  11866.70  16315.00   100   
 func4() 251098.18 265936.30 273667.45 275778.04 281740.77 291279.20   100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How is this compared to the Reduce method posted above?

Comment: @Josh - A speed test shows this answer is the fastest.

Comment: @Onyambu - The title of the OP's question is "rbind two lists in R element by element". Aside from that, I'm not sure how all these answers would scale without testing that, it's true. However, as a general rule, whenever you can use binary (i.e. TRUE, FALSE) in your code, it will speed things up a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarking test, but it seems like your function 3 is the only one to convert a matrix to a data frame. If you remove `data.frame` from function 3, function 3 becomes the fastest.

Comment: @ycw - These are all great answers; they are. And I'm trying to present an objective answer for the OP. So I just removed the data.frame() from the function you referenced and reran. See the update results above. It's much closer, but my answer is still the quickest in this specific use case.

Comment: I keep stuffing up my comment, but try it on large data instead of a very small example. `func3()` is considerably faster on large data like - `a <- a[rep(1:2,3e5)]; b <- b[rep(1:2,3e5)]` - measurement differences of `0.000005` seconds are not overly meaningful.

Comment: @thelatemail - That's a good idea; I'm running a large scale test now and will update the speed results when it's done.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer and benchmarking, and it is a great work Perhaps function 3 is not the fastest, but your original post including the `data.frame` is definitely not the objective way to compare the speed. I also ran the micro-benchmarking several times and sometimes function 3 is the fastest. Not always, but sometimes.

Comment: You could also shave a huge chunk off `func1` if you don't repeat `do.call(rbind, c(a,b))` - `func1mod <- function(){
  rbab <- do.call(rbind,c(a,b));
  rbind(rbab[c(TRUE,FALSE),],rbab[c(FALSE,TRUE),])
}` for instance.

Comment: @ycw - Thanks for mentioning data.frame(). You're absolutely right. I had just copy/pasted that into the comparison at first, before I thought to change that. The larger scale results are now in though; see the above edits. And thank you for all the constructive comments.

Comment: @thelatemail - Thanks for that speed tip and all this constructive dialogue. I was thinking about how best to simplify it for that reason. Great advice; see the update results above.

Comment: You have different results in `func1` and `func2` than the others.  `identical(func2(), func3())` is `FALSE`,  and `identical(func2(), func4())` is also `FALSE`.

Comment: @RichScriven - Oh, I think you're right, thanks. Something changed when scaled. If you run on the original sample it's the same. I'll double-check and rerun if needed soon.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Reduce(rbind,Map(rbind,a,b))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    3    4    5    6    7
 [3,]    2    3    4    5    6
 [4,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a new list with both a and b, and then make it a matrix. I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
a <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,4,5,6), c(1,1,1,1,1))
b <- list(c(3,4,5,6,7), c(4,5,6,7,8))

# empty list
ab <- vector("list", length = length(a) + length(b)) 
# put a and b in correct locations 
ab[seq(1, length(ab), 2)] <- a
ab[seq(2, length(ab), 2)] <- b
# make the matrix
res <- t(matrix(unlist(ab), nrow=5, ncol=length(a) + length(b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> ab <-rbind(unlist(a), unlist(b))
> ab <- rbind(ab[,1:5], ab[,6:10])
> ab
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7
[3,]    2    3    4    5    6
[4,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But is there a more general way to do this if the two lists contain a lot of vectors?

Comment: @Josh `do.call(rbind, c(a,b))`

Comment: Thanks Frank. But your solution creates something different from what I want. Yours would rbind all vectors in first list then rbind all vectors in second list.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

`d <- t(as.data.frame(c(a,b)))
 rbind( d[ seq(1,nrow(d),by=2) ,] , d[ seq(2,nrow(d),by=2) ,])`